# snapsvg - Add SVG inside SVG + events not working

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I have several SVG elements in a web page and I want to nest them. The problem I'm having is that when I do this using:

```
top = Snap("#workspace");
inner = Snap("#child");
top.add(inner);
```

Then `inner` does not respond to events, i.e. `inner.click(function....)` or `inner.drag()` don't do what's expected. Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt33Loec/1/). The `dots` object is not dragable, while `block` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't drag/transform an svg element itself, so that wouldn't work.

You can drag a g element though, so put the drag handler on that. You can do this instead.

```
var dots = Snap("#layer1");
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt33Loec/2/)